# Fetching retweet using twitter gem in ruby

Tags: ruby, rubygems, twitter-gem

I have been using twitter gem in ruby to fetch various attributes of a tweet. I have been successful in fetching all the attributes. However when i try to fetch retweet, it always gives me the value of 0.

```
require 'twitter'
geolocate = Twitter::Geo.new
client = Twitter::Streaming::Client.new do |config|
   config.consumer_secret   ="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" 
   config.consumer_key       = "YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY"
   config.access_token        ="ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ"
   config.access_token_secret ="AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"
end
client.filter(:locations => "-122.75,36.8,-121.75,37.8,-74,40,-73,41,-84.32,33.84,-75.45,36.58") do |object| 
if(object.is_a?(Twitter::Entities))
 if (object.geo.longitude.nil? == false)
   if(object.hashtags?) 
      puts  "Tweet: " +object.text.to_s if object.is_a?(Twitter::Tweet)
      puts  "Created At: " +object.created_at.to_s
      puts  "UserName: " +object.user.name.to_s
      puts  "retweets: " +object.retweet_count.to_s
     end
   end
  end
end
```

The retweet always gives me the value of zero
**Below is the sample output for some users.**

```
Tweet: #stevienicks #vibez champagne satin shirt/vest with tail... Has back waist tie, small/medium $32… https://t.co/m7I1rTEUeM
Created At: 2015-04-15 08:03:20 -0400
UserName: MAHPs Vintage 
retweets: 0
______________________________________________

Tweet: Kicking off day 2 of our spring leadership conference with a continuation of @JohnCMaxwell 's 5 levels of #leadership http://t.co/hNNC0tdYni
Created At: 2015-04-15 08:03:20 -0400
UserName: Hendrick Automotive 
retweets: 0
_____________________________________________

Tweet: Thanks God for another day!
Obrigado Deus por mais um dia 
#GoodMorning… https://t.co/klMwtfr7w3
Created At: 2015-04-15 08:03:29 -0400
UserName: Leonnardo Lima
retweets: 0
______________________________________________
Tweet:  #duke #whereisthegiraffeemoji #champs @ Monroe your Boat ⛵️ https://t.co/bw1AV67GMY
Created At: 2015-04-15 08:03:30 -0400
UserName: Gossip Garner
retweets: 0
```

So is there a way to get  **retweets by a particular user** 
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The `retweet_count` method returns a *read only* integer. As shown is the documentation [Ruby's Tweet documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/twitter/Twitter/Tweet). It is immutable, I suppose.

You should try this `puts  "retweets: #{object.retweet_count}"`.

Also, you don't need to change every attribute to string to print it. Just use it as shown above and you should do good.